# Plotting lines with gnuplot python

Tags: python, gnuplot

I have a list:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
```

Now using gnuplot, I have plotted the points as `(0,1), (1,2), ...`

Here is the syntax I used:

```
g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot()
g.plot(x)
```

Now I have my required set of points but I want to join these points by a line. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following work for you?

```
>>> import Gnuplot
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> gp = Gnuplot.Gnuplot()
>>> gp.title('My title')
>>> gp('set style data linespoints')
>>> gp.plot(x)
```

You can pass whatever options you want in the 5th command.